# Add a method to the setup of a Moq test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to get my head around moq and mvc. I have setup a moq and added a valid Setup to it.

My test to call my interface.

```
var id = 2;
var customer = new Customer()
{
    CustomerId = 2,
    FirstName = "Tomas",
    LastName = "Smith"
};

var moq = new Mock<ICustomerRepository>();
moq.Setup(x => x.Find(id, 1234))
   .Returns(Task.FromResult(customer));

var controller = new MyController(moq.Object);
var result = await controller.Get(id);
```

Now within my Get action I call my repository to get in this case a customer. However I need to pass in an extra parameter which is an int

```
var customer = await _repository.FindAsync(customerid, GetSourceId());
```

How can I moq GetSourceId() to return an int? without actually needing to call the method which I know will fail as its pulling data from the request header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If GetSourceId() is a method on the controller, you would have to mock the constructor via:

```
// mock takes params of constructor args
var ctlr = new Mock(Of MyController)(moq.Object);
ctlr.Setup(i => i.GetSourceId()).Returns(5);

var obj = ctlr.Object;
var result = obj.Get();
```

I was able to then call the action method directly on the mock, and it invoked the logic for me; I didn't need to do an explicit setup on the mock to call the original method.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Yes I was thinking there would be that downside.

Comment: Sorry Brian I thought I had it but I dont. So I use something similar to your example `var ctlr = new Mock<MyController>(moq.Object);ctlr.Setup(i => i.GetSourceId()).Returns(5); setups the GetSourceId. But where am I meant to setup the action I want to call?

Comment: Correction, I included a snippet above, using your example, of a situation that worked for me.  Calling the method on the object invokes the original method no problem.  The above solution is almost identical to mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
var getSource = Mock<IYourInterfaceHere>();
getSource.Setup(x => x.GetSource(YourParams)).Returns(1);
```

With Moq, if you are going to call your Get method, you will need to check all the methods that use this Get method in the call, and mock all of them, for example:

Your Get method inside, call a GetSource() and GetSource() inside, call another method called GetId(), then if you are trying to test your Get method, you will need to mock your GetSource() and your GetId() too. Like a cascade.